# What version of Visual Studio 2010 is required to run "web tests"?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-development, visual-studio-2010

I have some "Web Tests" that I've created in Visual Studio 2008 Team Test Edition.  I need to know which version of Visual Studio 2010 I will need to work with the tests I've created.  I don't see that there is a "Team Test Edition" of VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Web Performance Testing, and Load Testing](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx#compare) are only available in VS 2010 Ultimate

Comment: I saw Web Performance testing in the feature comparison you reference.  I don't know that "Web Performance Testing" is the same as "Web Testing".

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Web Testing" then.

Comment: The Web Test should be replaced by the Coded UI test, so you can create them with Premium, but using them for load testing will require Ultimate.  There is a post on Bruce Sterling's blog(http://blogs.msdn.com/charles_sterling/archive/2008/11/05/visual-studio-team-system-2010-test-features-walk-through-with-screen-shots.aspx#_Create_a_Coded) outlining how creating a coded UI test works on 2010